# how to set div in particular order like ascending or descending order to display in order

Tags: php, html

i have five div like this one as below.

```
 <div id="main">     
    <div order-id="5">5</div>   
    <div order-id="3">3</div>   
    <div order-id="2">2</div>   
    <div order-id="1">1</div>   
    <div order-id="4">4</div> 
 </div>
```

what i want to do is display this divs with order-id in ascending order

like output of above div as 1,2,3,4,5 (data of divs)
i have try by taking one array for order as

`$elements =array('1','2','3','4','5');`

and i have use this one as follow

```
<div id="main">

    <div order-id="<?php echo $elements[0]?>">5</div>   
    <div order-id="<?php echo $elements[1]?>">3</div>   
    <div order-id="<?php echo $elements[2]?>">2</div>   
    <div order-id="<?php echo $elements[3]?>">1</div>   
    <div order-id="<?php echo $elements[4]?>">4</div> 
 </div>`
```

but this one is not perfect working as order-id=0 is not takes.

any one have idea about this one. or any other method. this is my way to do and display the all divs in order which i have already define in array as my settings

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
$elements = array("1","2","3","4","5");

foreach ($elements as $key => $value) {
    echo "<div order-id='".$value."'></div>";
}
```

Comment: You should probably elaborate on your answer.